# How to change the value attribute of a dropdown option?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I want to change the value attribute of this dropdown option in the select form using JS DOM.

```
<select name="Party">
      <option id="partyreg" value="Party">Party</option>
</select>
```

However this doesn't seem to work:

```
document.getElementById("partyreg").value = partyCode;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works as it is. Have you checked the console for error messages? Please also explain what exactly are you expecting your code to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `partyCode` is not defined. I think you intend to use a string? Something like:

```
document.getElementById("partyreg").value = "partyCode";
```

Which doesn't generate an error in the console like your code does.

Note that this changes the value of the option, not the "value" you see in the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Hey [**@Zak**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9622736/zak),

If you want to change **attributes value,** then you could do like this:-

> `document.getElementById('partyreg').id = 'partyCode';`

or you can also do that as wall

> `document.getElementById('partyreg').setAttribute("id","div2")`

======================================================================

```html
<html>
<head>  
 <style>
        #partyreg {
            background: green;
        }
  
        #partyCode {
            background: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id='partyreg'>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById(
        'partyreg').id = 'partyCode';">
        click here
    </button>
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: How is your code example related to the question?

Comment: @Teemu DSDmark is still working on it... be patient...

Comment: @Teemu Yeah, I agree, the code example makes little sense.

Comment: Hey [@KIKO Software](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3986005/kiko-software),  
 I got it, I was little confused because he writes in question **change the value attribute** theywhy.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
document.getElementById("partyreg").setAttribute('value', partyCode)
```

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementByID("partyreg").setAttribute("value", partyCode)

Comment: Your code generates an error: _"Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function"_, nor do you explain why this line of code is an answer to the question.